# Else !string[i][j].equals(name) returns it j times minus the IF

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

OK. Full disclosure, this is a school assignment, I've solved everything but this not found statement and I can't figure it out for the life of me. It either prints it 999 times and prints the name is ranked year in the correct spot, and I've changed spots and moved it around tried a while loop, adding more to it. It's got to be something simple, I just can't pick it up.

The idea is to search the 10 different text files, find the name and print it's rank(index pretty much). I've got all that working, and I understand how to do it. I've commented out the if statement that I'm having trouble with. It's toward the bottom after the catch. It's the last segment of code. I also understand why it's doing it, as in the else is going through the loop and it doesn't equal 999 times, but I only want it to print if the name doesn't match any names at all.

Thanks for any and all help.

```
    public static void readNames() {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            String filename = "C:\\Users\\Rocketman\\Desktop\\JAVA\\babynameranking" + (2001 + i) + ".txt";
            try (Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(filename))) {
                for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                    input.nextInt();//rank
                    boyNames[i][j] = input.next();//boy name
                    input.nextInt();//boy amount
                    girlNames[i][j] = input.next();//girl name
                    input.nextInt();//girl amount
                    if (((year == 2001 + i) && (i == 0 + i)) || (year == 2010 && i == 9)) {
                        if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("m") || gender.equalsIgnoreCase("male")) {
                            if (boyNames[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                                System.out.println(name + " rank is " + (j + 1) + ".");
                            }
                        } else if (girlNames[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                            System.out.println(name + " rank is " + (j + 1) + ".");
                        }
                    }

                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
       // if ((!boyNames.equals(name) || !girlNames.equals(name))) {
       //     System.out.println(name + " is not ranked in " + year);
       // }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider showing us **only the relevant code.**

Comment: `boyNames` and `girlNames` are `2d arrays` and `name` is a `String`.  What do you mean by `equals` here?

Comment: Are you comparing an array with a string?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Come on, this is too harsh IMHO. I've seem much more and better interweaved spaghetti produced by some professionals.

Comment: @peter.petrov cruel to be kind. Agreed that professionals write code related to pasta products too, but it's a very bad habit to get into.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I agree, sure, in principle that's right. Either I am immuned by now, or you're too sensitive about this :). I personally don't find this spaghetti at all. Just a few nested loops.

Comment: @BoristheSpider This is the way the professor is requiring us to do this exercise. I had no control over that. I just did it, sorry it doesn't look that good. What should I have done different to make it look how you'd like?

Comment: Accepted best practice is to put code into methods. Each method should do only one thing. No method should be longer than 10 lines. This makes your code easy to follow - if you use good names for your methods then your code becomes self documenting.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `boolean` variable in the block where you process a particular file. Initialize it to false (this guy is not ranked). While processing the file, if you find he/she is ranked in that file, set it to true. Then at the end just check if that variable is true or false (replace your commented part with that check).

In general, this check `!boyNames.equals(name)` will not work as `boyNames` is a 2D array, it can never be equal to a String in Java.

See if this fixes your issue.

```
    public static void readNames() {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            String filename = "C:\\Users\\Rocketman\\Desktop\\JAVA\\babynameranking" + (2001 + i) + ".txt";
            try (Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(filename))) {
                boolean ranked = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                    input.nextInt();//rank
                    boyNames[i][j] = input.next();//boy name
                    input.nextInt();//boy amount
                    girlNames[i][j] = input.next();//girl name
                    input.nextInt();//girl amount
                    if (((year == 2001 + i) && (i == 0 + i)) || (year == 2010 && i == 9)) {
                        if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("m") || gender.equalsIgnoreCase("male")) {
                            if (boyNames[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                                System.out.println(name + " rank is " + (j + 1) + ".");
                                ranked = true;
                            }
                        } else if (girlNames[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                            System.out.println(name + " rank is " + (j + 1) + ".");
                            ranked = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!ranked){
                    System.out.println(name + " is not ranked in " + year);
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had it as !boyNames[i][j].equals(name) in the appropriate places. I'm trying the boolean now.

Comment: OK, answer updated. It is just a minor thing you were missing.

Comment: Thanks man. That mostly solved it, but it's still printing 9 from the i outer loop and the ranked spot. I'm playing with it though. This was the push I needed.

Comment: I just had to add another condition to it.                           if (!ranked && year==2001+i){
System.out.println(name + " is not ranked in " + year);
}